# Eliminating repeated code (DRY principle) in this chain of responsibility caching function

Tags: language-agnostic, dry

I am creating a Map Tile Server class, with a function `get_tile(tilekey)` which should do the following:

1. Try to retrieve the image from an in-memory dictionary (faster);
2. If not present, try to retrieve the image from disk;
3. If not present, try to download the image form the internet;

But, since I might call the same image soon after, I must also fill the faster cache layers when I have to use a slower one, and this is generating repeated code. Below is a Python-syntax-style pseudocode of what is working now:

```
## WARNING: this is Pseudo-Code!!

def get_tile(tilekey):
    if tilekey in tiles.keys():
        tileimage = tiles[tilekey]
    elif file.exists (tilekey + ".jpg"):
        tiles[tilekey] = open_image_from_disk(tilekey + ".jpg")
        tileimage = tiles[tilekey]
    else:
        download_image_to_disk(urltemplate + tilekey + ".jpg")
        tiles[tilekey] = open_image_from_disk(tilekey + ".jpg")
        tileimage = tiles[tilekey]
    return tileimage
```

I have this sort of "try to do f1; if not, do f2, f1; if not, do f3, f2, f1", and if this was deeper, then the amount of repeated code would grow geometrically.
I have the impression that some clever combination of some tricks like `try/except/finally` or recursion/delegation, or some other clever control flow construct might make things cleaner.

As a final note, I plan to implement this in more than one language (Python and C# at least), so it's more of a design-pattern question than a problem-specific, language-dependent question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
## WARNING: this is Pseudo-Code!!

def get_tile(tilekey):
  if !tilekey in tiles.keys():        
    if !file.exists (tilekey + ".jpg"):
      download_image_to_disk(urltemplate + tilekey + ".jpg")

    tiles[tilekey] = open_image_from_disk(tilekey + ".jpg")

  return tiles[tilekey]
```

Comment: And the oscar goes to... Thank you very much! It's so obvious now that it's written down...

Comment: @heltonbiker :) I'm a big fan of the KISS principle